# Simple logical condition flag MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I require help to develop some logic on the below data extract. I need the C2 column to toggle to '1' when C1 is '1'. Then, when C1 is '-1' the C2 column toggles to '0'. All rows in C2 between the C1 toggles (1 & -1) needs to turn to '1'.

```
Date           C1  C2
'24-Dec-1999'   0   0
'31-Dec-1999'   1   1
'07-Jan-2000'   0   1
'14-Jan-2000'   0   1
'21-Jan-2000'   0   1
'28-Jan-2000'   0   1
'04-Feb-2000'   -1  0
'11-Feb-2000'   0   0
'18-Feb-2000'   0   0
'25-Feb-2000'   0   0
```

I used the following, however it only changes the first and last entries on 31-DEC-1999 and 04-FEB-2000. How do I make it so that the entries in between (7-Jan-2000 to 28-Jan-2000) in C2 are also listed as '1'?

```
C2(C1==1)=1;
C2(C1==-1)=0;
```

Comment: Of course it'll only change entries where `C1 == 1` and `C1 == -1`. You haven't written any code to do the third part (rows between these must be `1`). Try to think of a condition that is `true` in between those rows and false otherwise. What if the number of `C1 == 1` is not the same as `C1 == -1`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by the last statement? "What if the number of C1 == 1 is not the same as C1 == -1?"

Comment: What if there are five elements of `C1` that are `1` but only one of `C1` that are `-1`?

Comment: That is not possible in my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

The easiest way to do this is calculate the cumulative sum

```
C2 = cumsum(C1);
```

---

**Original** / Alternative

You can find the indices where `C1=1` and where `C1=-1`, per your comments there should be an equal number of these

```
idxStart = find(C1=1); % Could use >0.5 to avoid numerical precision issues
idxEnd = find(C1=-1);  % Could use <-0.5 to avoid numerical precision issues
```

Then you just need to loop through them and make `C2=1` in between

```
C2 = zeros(size(C1));
for ii = 1:numel(idxStart)
    C2(idxStart(ii):idxEnd(ii)-1) = 1;
end
```